# What causes an "unexpected EOF while parsing" with this try except finally?

Tags: python, html, try-except

I have a web bot that looks at a textbox and gathers information. Depending on what page the textbox is on, the HTML is just slightly different.

This chunk of code repeatedly hits me with the syntax error "unexpected EOF while parsing" as soon as it sees the except block. I've written similar scripts that have worked no problem but this one has been giving me issues.

```
text_box = '/html/body/div[7]/div[45]/div[37]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[1]/span'
try:
    title = driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = text_box).text.split('\n')[0]
except NoSuchElementException:
    text_box = '/html/body/div[8]/div[45]/div[37]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[1]/span'
finally:
    title = driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = text_box).text.split('\n')[0]
    content = driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = text_box).text.replace(post_title + "\n" + "\n", "")
```

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This works fine for me (once I add some mock values for the variables that aren't defined in your snippet).  The error suggests an unclosed quote or something similar.  Are you positive that the error is in this code and it's on that particular line?  If so, try to create a MRE that other people can try to run *exactly as you've pasted it* instead of having to fill in gaps that might be affecting the behavior.

Comment: Also, are you using a reasonably modern version of Python?  If you're using an archaic interpreter knowing its exact version is important.